# Can't install Meteor Up / (mup)

Tags: node.js, bash, meteor, npm, meteor-up

After installing npm I typed:

```
npm install -g mup
```

It returned:

```
/Users/RyanCassutt/.node/bin/mup -> /Users/RyanCassutt/.node/lib/node_modules/mup/bin/mup
mup@0.11.1 /Users/RyanCassutt/.node/lib/node_modules/mup
├── colors@0.6.2
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── uuid@1.4.2
├── async@0.9.2
├── rimraf@2.4.2 (glob@5.0.14)
├── archiver@0.14.4 (buffer-crc32@0.2.5, lazystream@0.1.0, readable-stream@1.0.33, tar-stream@1.1.5, glob@4.3.5, zip-stream@0.5.2, lodash@3.2.0)
├── nodemiral@1.1.0 (debug@0.7.4, progress@1.1.5, async@0.9.0, underscore@1.8.3, ejs@0.8.8, ssh2@0.4.6)
└── cjson@0.3.1 (jsonlint@1.6.0)
```

I then try to create a new project:

```
mup init
```

But it returns:

```
-bash: mup: command not found
```

Is mup not installing correctly or is there some type of error? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `~/.node/bin` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: Hello! I think so... How can I check for sure? I appreciate the help!

Comment: `echo $PATH`. The variable contains _paths_ delimited by `:`. There should be something like `~/.node/bin` in there.

Comment: Ah, thank you! No there isn't, only this: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: OS X Yosemite. Thank you for trying to help! I had a similar problem with npm where it would come back as "command not found" but I was able to uninstall nom and then reinstall it with brew. I tried deleting all of my mup and telescope app files but I still got the same error/warning. Again, thank you!